# JavaFx: binding of a ObjectProperty<Integer> with a ObjectProperty<Unit>

Tags: binding, combobox, javafx-8

I have a scene with a `NumberSpinner` element and a `ComboBox` element and I want to bind the `minValue` property of the `NumberSpinner` element with the valueProperty of the `ComboBox` element. Some code:

```
@FXML
private NumberSpinner aNumberSpinner;
@FXML
private ComboBox<Unit> aComboBox;
```

where `Unit` is an `enum`:

```
public enum Unit {

    mm,
    degree
}
```

What I want is that when I choose `degree` `Unit` in `aComboBox` the `minValueProperty()` of `aNumberSpinner` become `10`. How can I achieve it?

Comment: a) let the Unit decide about its own minimum b) bind the slider's minValue to the combo's selectedItem, that is the selected unit

Comment: I can have more ComboBox<Unit> connected with more NumberSpinner and every NumberSpinner can have different minValue. If I let the Unit decide about its own minimum, I don't achieve this.

Comment: sounds like a fishy design to me - how would a view be able to decide about which of the "different" values might apply?

Comment: My view has more NumberSpinner. For example I can set minValue = 10 for numberSpinner1 and minValue=20 for numberSpinner2 with jewelsea's Pure Binding Solution

Comment: now you have me thoroughly confused (my bad, not yours, of course :-) Then how comes the binding of to the unit combo? Is it different combos (one per slider) as well?

Comment: Sorry. Yes, I have different combo, one for slider.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification :-) Anyway, I would suggest that you abstract those different combinations of minValue/unit into some model, would make your app much more robust than any manual config. Just my 2cents :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As suggested by Kleopatra in comments it is best if the unit knows its own minimum.

*Preferred solution - no binding*

My preferred solution for this wouldn't use a binding at all.

A listener on the combobox value can easily set the minimum value of your spinner object directly to the appropriate value by querying the minimum value from the unit newly selected in the combo box.

Sometimes it is possible to be a bit too tricky with bindings...

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class UnitMinimums extends Application {
    private enum Unit {
        mm(0), degree(10);

        private final int minValue;

        private Unit(int minValue) {
            this.minValue = minValue;
        }

        public int getMinValue() {
            return minValue;
        }
    }

    private Slider slider = new Slider(0, 20, 0);

    private ComboBox<Unit> combo = new ComboBox<>(
            FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                    Unit.values()
            )
    );

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        combo.valueProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) ->
                slider.setMin(newValue.getMinValue())
        );
        slider.setShowTickMarks(true);
        slider.setShowTickLabels(true);

        VBox layout = new VBox(5, slider, combo);
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        VBox.setVgrow(combo, Priority.ALWAYS);
        combo.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        combo.getSelectionModel().select(0);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

*Pure Binding Solution*

If you did want a pure binding solution, you could do something like below, but it has the disadvantage of scattering the information specific to the minimum value of the unit (which is intrinsic to the enum) all around the code if you started writing code like this a lot.

Use [Bindings.when](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#when-javafx.beans.value.ObservableBooleanValue-):

```
Bindings.when(
        combo.valueProperty().isEqualTo(Unit.degree)
    ).then(10)
     .otherwise(0)
```

*Executable Sample*

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class BoundMinimums extends Application {
    private enum Unit { mm, degree }

    private Slider slider = new Slider(0, 20, 0);

    private ComboBox<Unit> combo = new ComboBox<>(
            FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                    Unit.values()
            )
    );

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        slider.minProperty().bind(
                Bindings.when(
                        combo.valueProperty().isEqualTo(Unit.degree)
                ).then(10)
                 .otherwise(0)
        );
        slider.setShowTickMarks(true);
        slider.setShowTickLabels(true);

        VBox layout = new VBox(5, slider, combo);
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        VBox.setVgrow(combo, Priority.ALWAYS);
        combo.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

*On datatype conversion*

This gets a little complicated and non-obvious for me (which is another reason to sometimes prefer listeners and straight setters over binding), but I think you can do something like below, which coverts the `DoubleProperty` `slider.minProperty()` to an `ObjectProperty<Integer>`:

```
ObjectProperty<Integer> op = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(5);
op.bind(
    IntegerExpression.integerExpression(
        slider.minProperty()
    ).asObject()
);
```

Putting it together with the unit conversion, you get the following, which maybe even does what you want:

```
ObjectProperty<Integer> op = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(5);
op.bind(
    IntegerExpression.integerExpression(
        Bindings.when(
            combo.valueProperty().isEqualTo(Unit.degree)
        ).then(10)
         .otherwise(0)
    ).asObject()
);
```

Comment: cough .. the Unit itself should decide about its own minValue (vs. an unrelated binding)

Comment: Thanks! aNumberSpinner.minValueProperty() is a ObjectProperty<Integer>, so I have a compile error: The method bind(ObservableValue<? extends Integer>) in the type Property<Integer> is not applicable for the arguments (NumberBinding). How can I convert a NumberBinding in a Property<Integer>?

Comment: NumberBinding (or IntegerBinding, forgot where exactly) has a factory method to convert a Property<TYPE> to TYPEProperty

Comment: Sorry, but I think I have to obtain a Property<Integer> from a IntegerProperty. I know there is the asObject() method of IntegerProperty to do this, but now my problem is how "convert" a NumberBinding in a IntegerProperty.